# Netezza to snowflake function conversion

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, netezza

I am working on a task converting netezza to snowflake. So i need a solution to convert netezza create  function to snowflake create function.

Answer (score 0):

Netezza user defined functions are implemented in C++ and Snowflake user defined functions are in either SQL or Javascript, so a conversion isn't possible.  You will have to reimplement the function in Javascript or SQL.